# html form to php for emailing and error processing

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have searched for an answer to this and many are close to what I am looking for but no cigar yet!

I have an html form that when submitted goes to php. The php does some basic error checking/validation. If all is good then it sends an email. If there is a problem, I send an alert popup via:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";
```

My problem is that after the user clicks on the OK from the popup, I want to return the user to the form and have all the data they entered in the form, still residing in it so they don't have to retype. I have tried using the header refresh, but that brings me to a blank form.  I have tried various concoctions of a command similar to:

```
echo "<input class="field" type="text" name="first_name" value = "<?php echo $_POST['first_name']; ?>"/>";
```

but it never works for me. Plus, if this is the right thing to do, then I don't know exactly where to put it in the code (before the header command, after header but before the javascript alert, etc.) I also have problems with the syntax and coding of the line.

Any assistance that can be provided is greatly appreciated.

Here is the php file. The function died is where I am trying to make it work for me.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

    // CHANGE THE TWO LINES BELOW
    $email_to = "me@test.com";

    $email_subject = "form submission";

    function died($error) {
        // your error code can go here
        $message = "Sorry, but there are errors found with the form you submitted.\\n";
        $message .= $error. " \\n";
        $message .= "Please go back and fix these errors. \\n";
        header("Refresh: 0; url=contact-us.html");

        echo "<script type='text/javascript'>alert('$message');</script>";

        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists
    if(!isset($_POST['first_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['last_name']) ||
        !isset($_POST['email']) ||
        !isset($_POST['telephone']) ||
        !isset($_POST['comments'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');       
    }

    $first_name = $_POST['first_name']; // required
    $last_name = $_POST['last_name']; // required
    $email_from = $_POST['email']; // required
    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required
    $comments = $_POST['comments']; // required

    $error_message = "";
    $email_exp = '/^[A-Za-z0-9._%-]+@[A-Za-z0-9.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}$/';
  if(!preg_match($email_exp,$email_from)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Email Address you entered does not appear to be valid.\\n';
  }
    $string_exp = "/^[A-Za-z .'-]+$/";
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$first_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The First Name you entered does not appear to be valid.\\n';
  }
  if(!preg_match($string_exp,$last_name)) {
    $error_message .= 'The Last Name you entered does not appear to be valid.\\n';
  }
  if(strlen($comments) < 2) {
    $error_message .= 'The Comments you entered do not appear to be valid.\\n';
  }
  if(strlen($error_message) > 0) {
    died($error_message);
  }
    $email_message = "Form details below.\n\n";

    function clean_string($string) {
      $bad = array("content-type","bcc:","to:","cc:","href");
      return str_replace($bad,"",$string);
    }

    $email_message .= "First Name: ".clean_string($first_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Last Name: ".clean_string($last_name)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Email: ".clean_string($email_from)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Telephone: ".clean_string($telephone)."\n";
    $email_message .= "Comments: ".clean_string($comments)."\n";


// create email headers
$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
@mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);  

header('Location: /contactresponse.html');
?>


<?php
}
die();
?>
```

Comment: `refresh: 0` means reload IMMEDIATELY, so there's no time for the user to read that error output. and you are vulnerable to javascript injection errors - if that `$message` contains (say) a `'`, you'll cause a JS syntax error and kill the alert anyways.

Comment: I think the best way to do it by using **ajax**, it will submit your form without reloading the page.

Comment: Thank you for your comments. Taking your suggestion, I found an ajax solution that is working me.